# Mock not respecting dynamic parameters with mocktail and GetIt dependency injection

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, mocking, flutter-dependencies, stacked

I have a mock for a `SharedPreferencesService` that is supposed to return a true/false depending on whether it's the user's first time using the app.

I have a parameter in my method to initialize the mock service to set the value as true/false, with a default of true, but it just seems to always be returning the default value.

I suspect this might be an issue with how my locator is set up (I'm using GetIt locator to initialize my services).

### Dependency Injection

I'm using Mocktail for mocking my services.

I'm using a GetIt `locator` for dependency injection:

Here is my locator instance (in the main code):

```
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => AuthenticationService());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => FirestoreUserService());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => FirestoreGoalService());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => stacked_services.NavigationService());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => SharedPreferencesService());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => stacked_services.DialogService());
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => LoginAndUserService());
}
```

And here's how SharedPreferencesService is called in my system under test (SUT):

```
class LoginAndUserService {
  // MARK
  // Services
  final SharedPreferencesService _prefs = locator<SharedPreferencesService>();
```

My test group registers services in the setUp method:

```
void main() {
  group('LoginAndUserService Tests -', () {
    late LoginAndUserService sut;

    setUp(() {
      registerServices();

      sut = LoginAndUserService();
    });
```

Register services calls this:

```
void registerServices() {
  getAndRegisterSharedPreferencesServiceMock();
}
```

And that operates as follows:

```
SharedPreferencesServiceMock getAndRegisterSharedPreferencesServiceMock(
    {bool? firstTimeUsage}) {
  removeRegistrationIfExists<SharedPreferencesService>();
  var service = SharedPreferencesServiceMock();

  when(() => service.firstTimeUsingApp()).thenAnswer((_) async {
    if (firstTimeUsage == null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return firstTimeUsage;
    }
  });

  when(() => service.firstTimeAppUsageComplete()).thenAnswer((_) async => true);

  locator.registerSingleton<SharedPreferencesService>(service);
  return service;
}
```

So, by default, it is registering a version of this SharedPreferencesServiceMock that has the default value of `true`.

However, in my test, I call this specific method again, to re-register the sharedPreferencesServiceMock with a firstTimeUsage value of `false`.

### Specific Test Info

Here is my test - it should recreate the SharedPreferencesService with a firstTimeUsage value of false.

```
      test(
          'loadAuthenticationPage - firstTimeUsingApp set to value in sharedprefs',
          () async {
        // ARRANGE
        var service =
            getAndRegisterSharedPreferencesServiceMock(firstTimeUsage: false);

        // ACT
        await sut.loadAuthenticationPage();
        bool firstTimeUsingAppValue = await service.firstTimeUsingApp();
        print('SharedPrefs firstTimeUsingApp is $firstTimeUsingAppValue');
        var result = sut.firstTimeUsingApp;

        // ASSERT
        expect(result, false);
      });
```

However, both the print statement and the result are coming back as `true` so somehow the mock service must not be returning that value appropriately. Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Note: this seems to be related to unregistering and re-registering the `SharedPreferencesServiceMock` in the individual unit test. If I change the `registerServices` function to initially register the mock with a `firstTimeUsage` value of false, it works property. Still investigating whether there's another way I can make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found two solutions:

First, make sure I initialize the SUT *after* I update the locator.

```
test(
    'loadAuthenticationPage - firstTimeUsingApp set to value in sharedprefs',
    () async {
  // ARRANGE
  var service =
      getAndRegisterSharedPreferencesServiceMock(firstTimeUsage: false);
  // sut is specified in the group - I need to re-initialize this after the locator.
  sut = LoginAndUserService();

  // ACT
  await sut.loadAuthenticationPage();
  bool firstTimeUsingAppValue = await service.firstTimeUsingApp();
  print('SharedPrefs firstTimeUsingApp is $firstTimeUsingAppValue');
  var result = sut.firstTimeUsingApp;

  // ASSERT
  expect(result, false);
});
```

The other is just overriding the `when` response directly in my test, instead of in my loading of the locator.

I'm still interested in whether there's a way to do this in the loads of my locator, but this seems to work properly.

```
      test(
          'loadAuthenticationPage - firstTimeUsingApp set to value in sharedprefs',
          () async {
        // ARRANGE
        var service = locator<SharedPreferencesService>();
// update my when response manually here.
        when(() => service.firstTimeUsingApp()).thenAnswer((_) async => false);

        // ACT
        await sut.loadAuthenticationPage();
        bool firstTimeUsingAppValue = await service.firstTimeUsingApp();
        print('SharedPrefs firstTimeUsingApp is $firstTimeUsingAppValue');
        var result = sut.firstTimeUsingApp;

        // ASSERT
        expect(result, false);
      });
```